# Unable to get access token for lyft api

Tags: access-token, lyft-api

I am trying to use the lyft developer api. I created a new app to get the client Id and client secret . I am following the steps in https://developer.lyft.com/docs/authentication to get an access token in my python code. But I always get the error, "unauthorized client". Can anyone point out my mistake?

```
def __init__(self):
    self.client_id = 'MY_ID'
    self.client_secret = 'MY_SECRET'

    # obtain access token
    self.token = self.__generate_token__()

    # define variables to be used in the request parameters
    token_val = 'Bearer '+self.token
    self.headers = {'Authorization':token_val}

def __generate_token__(self):
    url = 'https://api.lyft.com/oauth/token'

    # define request parameters
    payload = {"Content-Type": "application/json",
               "grant_type": "client_credentials",
               "scope": "public"}
    # request data
    res = requests.post(url,
                        data = payload,
                        auth = (self.client_id, self.client_secret))
    # extract the token from the response
    token = res.json()['access_token']
    return token
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example for a Java client

https://github.com/yschimke/oksocial/blob/175bdbf66e312d8bdf79183a140c2c5270329cf2/src/main/java/com/baulsupp/oksocial/services/lyft/LyftClientAuthFlow.java

The main thing that looks wrong, is sending "Content-Type" in the POST data body instead of as a header indicating the format of the data.

It looks like from the [requests api](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/3ea3324434ed82210416e847a4b27e620f534bd2/requests/api.py) that you should be sending "json = payload" instead of "data".  But I'm not an expert on this python API.

The curl equivalent of the above java code also works

```
$ ./oksocial --curl --authorize lyft --client
Authorising Lyft API
Lyft Client Id [***********]:
Lyft Client Secret [********************************]:
curl -X POST -H "Authorization:Basic ******************" -H "Connection:Keep-Alive" -H "User-Agent:okhttp/3.5.0" -H "Host:api.lyft.com" -H "Accept-Encoding:gzip" -H "Content-Length:55" -H "Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8" -H "Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8" -d '{"grant_type": "client_credentials", "scope": "public"}' https://api.lyft.com/oauth/token
```